# How to make seekBar bubble onClick

Tags: android, addeventlistener, android-seekbar

I want the parent view to reset a timeout every time the user touch on the views inside a container view. It works well except for the seekBar View that doesn't bubble any click.

**Update:**

The listener is set at the parent view like this:

```
  this.setAddStatesFromChildren(true);//has no effect

  this.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "reset hide timer: ");
            handler.removeCallbacks(hideCallback);
            //playerControls is a compound view
            playerControls.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

            handler.postDelayed(hideCallback, 5000);
        }
    });
```

This code catch all events from the child views but fail to get events from the seekbar inside the playerControls view. The view have other components that bubble events, just not seekbar.

The parent view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/bar">

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/show"
    />

<..PlayerControls
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/player_controls"
    android:layout_below="@id/show"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the child view (PlayerControls):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/player_controls"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/duration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you already try to implement `onProgressChanged` in your Seekbar?

Comment: yes, i am using it

Comment: But it is not being called?

Comment: yes, it is being called. But the seekBar is inside a compound View, so i can't use that event due to encapsulation

Comment: Can you show me some code?

Comment: Just post an update

Comment: And, what about the layout files? I need to see them as well.

Comment: I will try to put a simplified version that respects the same hierarchy and attributes.